# Should POST request be sent to the same path or the next page path?

Tags: http, express, networking, routes

Lets say we are designing a website that needs a number of steps to get input from the user. The user will submit the data using `POST` and get the form html page using `GET`. When the user is submitting the form, should it be submitted to the same route or the next one?

lets assume
current page form: `/golf/member/`
next page form: `/golf/arena/`

method 1 (post to same page):
- `POST` to `/golf/member/`
- Get redirected to `/golf/arena/`

method 2 (post to next page):
- `POST` to `/golf/arena/`
- Get redirected to `/golf/arena/`

Answer (score 0):

**Simpler solution:**

This is an interesting problem, and there are many ways you could do it. My first instinct is to try and disconnect what the user is seeing from your services requirements. I'm guessing you're just using a HTML form to do the post, it might be worth doing an ajax request and then redirecting the user with the client side (browser side) code instead. That way you can post to `/golf/member`, the API can just return a `201 Created` and your client side code can move them onto the next step which might be `/golf/arena` which can do the same again.

**More advanced solution:**

If this is a big feature with tons of different fields, I'd maybe even consider taking it a step further. You could get the server-side code to power the whole "flow" for the user. For example...

You could have an endpoint which is something like `POST /feature/start`, this endpoint might return some json such as:

```
{
    "title": "Form page 1",
    "form": {
        "title": "Form title",
        "fields": [
            { "title": "first name", "type": "input" },
            { "title": "surname", "type": "input" }
        ],
        "actions": [
            { "label": "Next", "type": "button", "method": "POST", "url": "/feature/next"
        ]
    }
}
```

Each step can then return a new version of this standard JSON structure, you can then interpret this JSON structure on the client side and use it to display the form you need at each step.

The above is just an example, and the URLs could be named better, but the conept would mean you're powering the data collection from the server-side and you're just using the front end to build the HTML and then collect the values and send them to the backend service. This can be really handy for large form systems like registering for a passport or something. Your frontend is then quite dumb and you only need to change the server-side code if you need to add or remove steps / fields.